# problem running VS-Code on conda environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

as the title states, i tried to run the conda environment from VS-code, it shows i'm in the environment but im facing a lot of problems like many libraries are not installed even through they are and the GPU is not running on trainings using tensorflow.

The only way is to close VS-Code and open it through anaconda prompt by typing "code". this way everything is perfect.

Is there a way i can bypass opening vs-code from anaconda prompt everytime i need to use one of its virtual environment?

Thnaks.

its fully functional if i open it through anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python: Select Interpreter`** command in vscode to select the conda interpreter.

[image]

The interpreter being used may be displayed in the lower right corner of the vscode interface. You can also click on it to switch.

[image]

Under the default settings, after you select a virtual environment, creating a new terminal will automatically activate the environment.

[image]

You can install the packages you need in the terminal that activates the environment to ensure that the packages are correctly installed in the conda environment.

[*More information can be read here.*](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)